# XSLT 1.0 - How to find a non alphanumeric character in the string

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In XSLT 1.0, How to find a non-alphanumeric character from the string
For e.g. it should return character '&' from string 'Hello&World'

Please advise.

Comment: I think you mean *"from string 'Hello&amp;World'"*?

Comment: It is basically to find any character other than [a-zA-Z0-9].

Comment: That is exactly what my answer does. But you cannot have an unescaped ampersand character in XML.

Comment: I am looking to only find non-alphanumeric character, but your answer is replacing that non-alphanumeric character which is not what am looking for.

Comment: The answer does exactly what you asked for. If that's not what you want, you need to express your requirement more clearly. Please supply example input and output for the XSLT transformation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define "alphanumeric". Perhaps you could do:

```
translate($yourString, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', '')
```